# How to create an animation of a rotating shape?

Tags: animation, 2d, svg

I am very new to blender. I would like to animate this [SVG file](http://svgur.com/i/cyZ)

- Below is the SVG file, and below is a screenshot of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="SVGRoot" width="151.2mm" height="143.79mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 151.2 143.79" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <defs>
  <marker id="TriangleStart" overflow="visible" markerHeight="20.027746" markerWidth="17.323999" orient="auto-start-reverse" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 5.3244081 6.15538509">
   <path transform="scale(.5)" d="m5.77 0-8.65 5v-10z" fill="context-stroke" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="context-stroke" stroke-width="1pt"/>
  </marker>
 </defs>
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g transform="translate(-74.503 -36.09)" stroke="#000">
  <path d="m197.88 107.95a53.047 53.047 0 0 1-53.047 53.047 53.047 53.047 0 0 1-53.047-53.047 53.047 53.047 0 0 1 53.047-53.047 53.047 53.047 0 0 1 53.047 53.047z" fill="none" stroke-width=".26458"/>
  <rect x="137.8" y="48.706" width="16.757" height="12.347" fill="#0f0" fill-opacity=".99314" stroke-width=".26458"/>
  <path d="m141.84 107.94h6m-3-3v6" fill="none" stroke-width=".5"/>
  <path d="m131.55 80.351a13.633 12.828 0 0 1 11.149-7.0024 13.633 12.828 0 0 1 12.131 5.3647" fill="none" marker-start="url(#TriangleStart)" stroke-width=".27962"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[image: Screenshot of the SVG file]

I need to rotate the rectangle in a circular path (following the circle).

Could someone please guide me on how to proceed?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about animating the SVG file itself, but if what you need is an animation that does what you're asking, you could certainly use the SVG as a template to create yourself a cube and a circular path object to get started.

As mentioned, start by making sure your scene has both of those objects.

Select your cube, go to the object constraints tab and choose Follow Path. It should look like this:

[image]

Note: If you click the Follow Curve option, the cube will rotate as it moves along the path like a train on tracks. If you don't, it'll just move without rotating.

Now all you need to do is hit that Animate Path button and you're good. Adjust the size of your cube as required. Note that the Animate Path button will create an animation at a predetermined speed, so if you want to manually animate it, you can do so by using keyframes to adjust the Offset value.

To do that, don't click Animate Path (or Undo if you have), and follow these instructions:

At frame 1, hover your mouse over the Offset value.

Press the I key (this is the keyboard shortcut for adding a keyframe)

Move to another frame further along.

Set the Offset to 100 (this represents one full 360º turn).

With your mouse hovering over the value, press the I key again.

Go back to frame 1 and hit play. It should animate around the path nicely. Look in your timeline and you'll see the keyframes represented by little diamond shapes. Move the second keyframe around to adjust the speed.

Now to set up the frame and shoot the animation!

Move your camera upwards and point it down. With your camera still selected, go into the Camera settings tab and change the Type from Perspective to Orthographic. This will eliminate perspective warp and give you a flat box when viewed from the top. Like so:

[image]

To recreate the shapes in your SVG, we're going to shoot a bird's eye view of your scene. Look up a basic guide if you need help setting up your frame range, materials and render engine/settings.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I need to animate the SVG because usually it contains shapes that I can't reproduce on Blender.

Comment: @OK-Validation I see! In that case you may need to use something like After Effects. Blender, to my knowledge, does not have vector animation capabilities like this, but I could be wrong. It does have a 2D animation toolset, though, so it may be possible.